# Как правильно получить данные с другого сайта?

Tags: php, json, api

У меня есть два сайта на разных серверах. Нужно на одном вывести данные из другого. Я могу подключиться к базе данных нужного сайта. Но нормально ли так делать? Лучше сделать API и подключаться к нему?

Comment: можно как угодно. взвесьте все за и против. Но все же API подразумевает некий "контракт", оговоренный формат передачи данных, и выдача API никак не будет меняться из-за возможных изменений структуры БД  стороннего (хоть и вашего) сайта.

Comment: Выше правильно написали можно и так и так. Если у вас не будет дубляжа бизнес логики после выборки данных на обоих серверах то смело можно подключаться к базе - это справедливо для каких-нибудь view в бд, т.е например готовые отчеты. Если у вас будут инсерты, что подразумевает дублирование логики, то тут только апи.

Comment: Ну и надо понимать что если база разрешает подключение извне, то может найтись какой-нибудь хацкер, который попытается до нее достучаться. Так что это подключение стоит каким-либо образом ограничить.